# How can you create a SQL connection for a Logic App for an ISE database in Visual Studio?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

How can you create a SQL connection for a Logic App for an ISE database in Visual Studio?

We can create the logic app and add a SQL connection in the Portal, but can't do the similar in Visual Studio

Even if we create in the Portal, and then download into Visual Studio using the Cloud Explorer, we then get "connection resource" errors, as VS can't connect to the ISE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available at this time but should become available pretty soon. In the meantime, please keep a close eye on new release on:

[Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsForVS2019&ssr=false#overview)